# I need to use code from another branch

Tags: git, merge, branch

Good day everone,

My question is, if i am in a particular branch working on my own feature, **FEATURE A**.
And someone else is working on branch **FEATURE B**.

We also have a main branch **DEVELOPMENT**

But the 2 features work together, for example lets say that **FEATURE A** observes for changes in **FEATURE B**.

I have done a few merges, merging my **FEATURE A** branch into **DEVELOPMENT** but always this 1 direction. So my **FEATURE A** branch only has code that i created, while **DEVELOPMENT** has code from both features. But now i want to implement the listener that interacts with **FEATURE B**, so how do i do this?
I dont have access to that code form my branch.

**DEVELOPMENT** branch is used by multiple people, so i can't just start working in there i assume.

Comment: is it not possible to merge the feature B branch into your feature A branch?

Comment: or merge the development branch to your FEATURE A

Comment: Why can't you work in DEVELOPMENT? That would be ideal - it's called continuous integration, which, among other benefits, avoids problems caused by the feature branches - like the one you're asking about...

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the code from branch B, or just [cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) some commits from branch B